# UITableView CoreData order with sections

Tags: swift, uitableview, cocoa-touch, core-data, swift2

I'm searching around to find some similar scenario but I cannot find anything that contains all features that I need. Looking around I wrote the implementation of the method moveRowAtIndexPath like the following but I have some issue with modifying the reference to the coredata objects so when I click done nothing is saved on coredata.

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, moveRowAtIndexPath sourceIndexPath: NSIndexPath, toIndexPath destinationIndexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    userDrivenDataModelChange = true;

    if (sourceIndexPath == destinationIndexPath) {
        return
    }

    let rooms = fetchedResultsController.sections!

    let sourceRoom = rooms[sourceIndexPath.section]
    let destinationRoom = rooms[destinationIndexPath.section]

    var sourceLights = sourceRoom.objects as! [Light]
    var destinationLights = destinationRoom.objects as! [Light]
    let light = sourceLights[sourceIndexPath.row]

    sourceLights.removeAtIndex(sourceIndexPath.row)
    destinationLights.insert(light, atIndex: destinationIndexPath.row)

    (destinationLights as NSArray).enumerateObjectsUsingBlock({ object, index, stop in
        let light = object as! Light
        light.position = index
    })

    tableView.reloadData()

    Utils.saveContext(getAppDelegate().context)

    userDrivenDataModelChange = false;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The part that was missing was setting the new room to the item that I was going to move. Something like:

```
item.relationRoom = <destination room object>
```

Also it needs some adjustment when you move a light within the same room.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is unnecessarily complex. You can get the light object in one line.

```
let light = fetchedResultsController.objectAtIndexPath(sourceIndexPath) as! Light
```

Updating the `position` property of the light is actually something that IMO belongs to the `Room` class. You should write convenience methods that renumber all relevant light instances when adding and removing (and maybe moving) light objects.

Notice that you might have to call this on two different rooms if a light is moved to a different room (i.e. the source and destination index paths have different sections).

Also, you do **not** need to reload the entire table view. That's completely redundant and bad UX if you are not already at the top of the table.

Please note that in your code you are just modifying the `sections` array from the fetched results controller. I order to save to core data you have to modify the relationships (presumably to `Room`) and save.

Comment: Good tip about getting the light object. But about the ordering this is done already via the enumerateObjectsUsingBlock method, but the change is not persisted somehow to CoreData, is maybe that the object is detached from CoreData and if so - how to solve it?

Comment: This code does not belong in a view controller. You should follow my recommendation.

Comment: ok, do you have an example? I still don't understand how to make my code working.

Comment: You need to modify the `Room` object to which the `Light` objects belong, not your copy of the sections from the `fetchedResultsController`.